# Generate Ethereum address from a private key

Tags: php, ethereum, php-openssl

I am trying to generate an Ethereum address based on a given private key following this "[How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)" and using this [Keccak-256 Ethereum implementation.](https://github.com/particlePaul/keccak256)
But it show this error:

```
Warning: openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /localweb/getethaddress.php on line 15
```

My implementation:

```
    // Format the private key as PEM
    $header_private_key = "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    $footer_private_key = "\n-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----";

    $eth_private_key = $header_private_key . "1a63b5c735d66d827f40f7d3a257da777cd7997d48bd5d319c36683c0ad3b1de" . $footer_private_key;

    // Load private key from a string
    $private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($eth_private_key);
    var_dump($private_key);
    while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
        echo "openssl_pkey_get_private " . $msg . "<br />\n";

    // Get the Public key
    $_public_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($private_key)['key'];
    $eth_public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public($_public_key);

    // hash the public key
    $hash_public_key = Keccak256\Keccak256::hash($eth_public_key, 256);; 
    $eth_address = '0x' . substr($hash_public_key, -40);

    // compare the output
    echo 'Your generated address: ' . $eth_address . '<br>';
    echo 'Myetherwallet address: 0x47180b59dd8c81f46186900bbd29cbf675b3fbd9';


    /*
        ad 40: 47180b59dd8c81f46186900bbd29cbf675b3fbd9
        pk 64: 1a63b5c735d66d827f40f7d3a257da777cd7997d48bd5d319c36683c0ad3b1de
    */
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I am getting those errors:

```
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
openssl_pkey_get_private error:10092010:elliptic curve routines:d2i_ECPrivateKey:EC lib
openssl_pkey_get_private error:100DE08E:elliptic curve routines:OLD_EC_PRIV_DECODE:decode error
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib
```

Comment: it means your `openssl_pkey_get_private($eth_private_key);`isnt returning resource object which is required by `openssl_pkey_get_details` ,  instead it is returning `false` probably because its failing, try to `var_dump` the `$private_key`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam `var_dump($private_key);` returns bool(false), unfortunately it doen't help much because provide no information.

Comment: Use the `openssl_error_string()` to find the actual error message http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Now it produces much informative informations about the error, please look at the update I did.

Comment: try to add the whole key into a single variable along with header and footers  it should look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/efAJ6) and if it still gives the same error there is a strong chance your key is corrupted and you need to regenerate it

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The private key is un-corrupted because i generate an empty wallet from Myetherwallet to compare the final result with it, however the key is in hex format if that help to solve my issue.

Comment: have you tried the way i said cuz error state `header too long` and `bad object header`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes I did and still getting errors.